# sampling based on frequency in R

Tags: r, random, histogram, sample

I want to make 20000 sample from a data which is quite big,based on the each value size in order to fill the `NA` values:
so I use the output of histogram, but it wasn't successful, and get me an error, how to avoid it ?

```
y=hist(maindata,col="red",breaks=length(unique(maindata))
for(k in 1:20000){
data=maindata
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
if (data[i]="Na"){
 data[i]=sample(y$breaks,size=1,replace=FALSE,prob=y$density)}}}
```

I get this error :

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

and I check the `length(y$breaks)` and `length(y$density)`,`length(y$breaks)` was one unit more, how should I fixed it ?

thank you in advance

**EDIT** :

```
    structure(list(breaks = c(15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 
40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 
56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 
72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 
88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 
103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109), counts = c(27L, 17L, 31L, 
83L, 118L, 144L, 211L, 279L, 354L, 312L, 300L, 377L, 407L, 443L, 
481L, 351L, 302L, 236L, 248L, 178L, 141L, 101L, 77L, 80L, 63L, 
44L, 64L, 44L, 60L, 46L, 24L, 29L, 15L, 28L, 21L, 13L, 19L, 10L, 
30L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L), density = c(0.00453172205438067, 
0.00285330647868412, 0.00520308828465928, 0.0139308492782813, 
0.0198053037932192, 0.0241691842900302, 0.035414568647197, 0.0468277945619335, 
0.0594159113796576, 0.0523665659617321, 0.0503524672708963, 0.0632762672037596, 
0.0683115139308493, 0.0743538100033568, 0.0807317891910037, 0.0589123867069486, 
0.0506881503860356, 0.0396106075864384, 0.0416247062772743, 0.0298757972473985, 
0.0236656596173212, 0.0169519973145351, 0.0129237999328634, 0.0134273246055723, 
0.0105740181268882, 0.00738502853306479, 0.0107418596844579, 
0.00738502853306479, 0.0100704934541793, 0.0077207116482041, 
0.0040281973816717, 0.00486740516951997, 0.00251762336354481, 
0.00469956361195032, 0.00352467270896274, 0.00218194024840551, 
0.00318898959382343, 0.00167841557569654, 0.00503524672708963, 
0.0018462571332662, 0.00201409869083585, 0.00201409869083585, 
0.00117489090298758, 0.00201409869083585, 0.00201409869083585, 
0.0018462571332662, 0.0018462571332662, 0.00117489090298758, 
0.00117489090298758, 0.000671366230278617, 0.000671366230278617, 
0.000671366230278617, 0.000167841557569654, 0.000335683115139308, 
0.000503524672708963, 0.00100704934541793, 0.000167841557569654, 
0.000167841557569654, 0.000503524672708963, 0.000503524672708963, 
0, 0, 0, 0.000167841557569654, 0.000167841557569654, 0, 0, 0, 
0.000167841557569654, 0, 0, 0.000167841557569654, 0, 0.000167841557569654, 
0, 0.000167841557569654, 0, 0.000167841557569654, 0.000167841557569654, 
0, 0, 0.000167841557569654, 0.000167841557569654, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.000503524672708963, 0, 0, 0, 0.000167841557569654, 0.000335683115139308
), mids = c(15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 
24.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 
35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 45.5, 
46.5, 47.5, 48.5, 49.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 55.5, 56.5, 
57.5, 58.5, 59.5, 60.5, 61.5, 62.5, 63.5, 64.5, 65.5, 66.5, 67.5, 
68.5, 69.5, 70.5, 71.5, 72.5, 73.5, 74.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 
79.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, 
90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 95.5, 96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 99.5, 100.5, 
101.5, 102.5, 103.5, 104.5, 105.5, 106.5, 107.5, 108.5), xname = "b", 
    equidist = TRUE), .Names = c("breaks", "counts", "density", 
"mids", "xname", "equidist"), class = "histogram")
```

**Data information** :

```
> head(maindata)
[1] 30 44 -1 32 30 34
> is.numeric(maindata)
[1] TRUE
> is.vector(maindata)
[1] TRUE
> length(maindata)
[1] 36203
```

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel,thanks for the comment, it is quite big , but I include it ,please see the edit part

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel : `"Na"` values are changed with -1

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want 20,000 samples from the distribution of the non-missing data? If so, another way to approach this would be to just calculate a kernel density estimate directly from the non-missing data and then sample from that. For example, using fake data:

```
# Fake data with some missing values
set.seed(31)
dat = rnorm(30000, 20, 10)
dat[sample(1:30000, 5000)] = NA

# Create kernel density estimate from the data
# n is the number of grid points used in the esimate (should always be a power of 2)
dat.dens = density(dat[!is.na(dat)], n=2^10)

sim.sample = sample(dat.dens$x, 2e4, replace=TRUE, prob=dat.dens$y)

plot(dat.dens)
lines(density(sim.sample), col="red")
```

[image]

Please let me know if I've misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks for your answer,let me paraphrase what I am trying to do, i would like to fill the missing value 20000 times, so I want to choose a random value for each missing value from non-missing value with the frequency probability for each .

Comment: I guess, with your answer I may get some values which may not be included in main data (but in the range), rigth?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you just want to sample values that are in your data, and your data vector has a distribution of values that is similar to the distribution in the underlying population that you're studying, then you can just sample from your data vector directly: `sim.sample = sample(maindata[!is.na(maindata)], 20000, replace=TRUE)`.

Comment: However, if the missing values are not missing at random, then both your histogram method or sampling directly from the data will give biased results. To get unbiased samples you'd need to weight the sampling by the actual distribution of the population (assuming you know what that distribution is), rather than by the distribution of the data.

Comment: thanks,I want them to be biased towards the population distribution.which would be assume to be the same.