# How to sample data based off the distribution of another dataset in R

Tags: r, sampling, kernel-density

I would like to sample a large dataset based on the distribution of a smaller dataset in R. I have been searching for a solution for some time without success. I am relatively new in R so I apologize if this is straightforward. However, I have tried some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388297/sampling-based-on-frequency-in-r).

Here are some sample data. I'll call it observed and model:

```
# Set seed
set.seed(2)

# Create smaller observed data
Obs <- rnorm(1000, 5, 2.5)

# Create larger modeled data
set.seed(2)
Model <- rnorm(10000, 8, 1.5)
```

The distributions of the two datasets are as follows:
[image]

Goal: I would like to sample the larger "model" dataset to match the smaller "observed". I understand that there are different data points involved so it won't be a direct match.

I have been reading up on the `density()` and `sample()` where I do the following:

```
# Obtain the density of the observed at the length of the model.
# Note: info on the sample() function stated the prob argument in the sample() function 
# must be the same length as what's being sampled. Thus, n=length(Model) below.

dens.obs <- density(Obs, n=length(Model))

# Sample the Model data the length(Obs) at the probability of density of the observed
set.seed(22)
SampleMod <- sample(Model, length(Obs), replace=FALSE, prob=dens.obs$y)
```

This gives me the new plot that looks very similar to the old (except for the tails):
[image]

I was hoping for a better match. Therefore I started explored using the density function on the model data. See below:

```
# Density function on model, length of model
dens.mod <- density(Model, n=length(Model))

# Sample the density of the model $x at the density of the observed $ y
set.seed(22)
SampleMod3 <- sample(dens.mod$x, length(Obs), replace=FALSE, prob=dens.obs$y)
```

Here are two plots, the first is the same as the first sampled and the second is the second sampled:
[image]

There is a more desirable shift in the right plot, which represents the sampled density of the modeled by the density of the observed. However, the data are not the same. That is, I did NOT sample the Modeled data. See below:

```
summary(SampleMod3 %in% Model)
```

produces:

```
   Mode   FALSE    NA's 
logical    1000       0
```

Indicating that I did not sample the modeled data, but rather the density of the modeled data. Is it possible to sample a dataset based on the distribution of another dataset? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the help guys! Here is my plot using `approxfun()` function offered from danielson and supported by bethanyp.

[image]

Any help with understanding why the funky new distribution?

Comment: did you ever come to understand your funky new distribution, or find an improved approach to your original question?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  I think this will help.  First, it approximates the density function.  Then, it samples from the Model points with the fitted density's probabilities.

```
predict_density = approxfun(dens.obs) #function that approximates dens.obs
#sample points from Model with probability distr. of dens.obs
SampleMod3 <- sample(Model, length(Obs), replace=FALSE, prob=predict_density(Model))
summary(SampleMod3 %in% Model)
   Mode    TRUE    NA's 
logical    1000       0
```

Comment: Looks like we were writing the same answer in two different ways at the same time. I went for the explanation, you went for the how-to function...great call! Always good to know I am on the right track!

Comment: Thanks to you both. I used the "how-to" solution outlined above and got the distribution in the edited section of my question (above). Any help for understanding the funky new distribution?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in practice you are using a real set of non-randomly generated data. In which case the likely values of the different samples have a probability of coming up because random sampling method does not mean no pattern in the data. In the wilderness real things have real frequencies, which will show in your meta-sample.

So you should use the weighted probabilities in selecting your smaller sub-sample from the original.

Example the whole population  {1,2,1,3,4,1,3}
where probabilities for each number being drawn (remember the sum must equal 1):
1 : .4285
2 :.1429
3: .2857
4: .1429

if you use these weighted probabilities in the `prob= my_freqs` part of

```
sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = my_freqs)
```

You will likely obtain a probability more inline with what you were expecting. But I am not 100% sure if this is what you are after.

In the random data, try `set.seed(2)` and see if telling R to use the seed used to generate those frequencies in the original set creation gets you closer to your goal.

I know that there is a universal random formula associated with each set. I would have to assume it is a set of frequency probabilities of a method of generating them for various sets of random methods, so it might help you o use that prior to sampling from the random sets.