# How to ensure the selected mean of sampled data from non-normally distributed data

Tags: r, distribution, sample

I have data with 10000 instances, which resemble negative binomial distribution. I am sampling out of this data, but I need a subsample which is normally distributed and has a pre-specified mean. How can I achieve this?

```
library(MASS)
my_trees <- rnegbin(10000, mu = 15, theta = 3)
hist(my_trees)
mean(my_trees)

my_sample <- sample(my_trees, size = 500)
hist(my_sample) 
mean(my_sample)
```

How can I sample data which will be normally distributed with a mean of, e.g. 25? I am aware of `prob` argument, and also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495240/how-to-sample-data-based-off-the-distribution-of-another-dataset-in-r) related question, but anyhow I can not get what I want.

Comment: Maybe `rnorm` is what you're looking for. Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/compositions/versions/1.40-3/topics/rnorm) for further details and examples.

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t see how to apply this function to sample from the existing space? As I can see it simply generates random samples which are normally distributed?

Comment: I apologize if I have overlooked something, but in the compositions R package, there are different PRE-DEFINED spaces that can be used to generate normally distributed samples. But I don’t see any option of supplying your own space and sample from this one. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Normal distribution have two parameters ; location parameter and scale parameter.
You mentioned only mean (25) then you can generate n random values distributed from normal distribution with `rnorm(n, mean = 25)`. For different sd(scale parameter), use `rnorm(n, mean, sd)`. In the same way you generate `my_trees` with `rnegbin`, `rnorm` does the same job.
https://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/old/5101/rlook.html provides information about several other distributions.

Comment: Yes, rnorm generates a random sample, but I need to sample out of existing (negative binomial) distribution. Why is this so important? My data is actually a real forest with trees, and I am trying to simulate harvesting, so the sampled trees will later be removed from the initial NB distribution. Do you think I can still use rnorm for my task?

Comment: @JerryTheForester May I ask for more information about ' sample out of existing (negative binomial) distribution' , especially "out of existing" part.

Comment: In my question, you can see the variable ‘my_trees’. This is my existing space with trees and their diameter. Now, I need to sample 500 trees out of ‘my_trees’, which will have a mean DBH of 25 and then remove them from ‘my_trees’ variable.

Comment: @JerryTheForester From my_trees data, sample 500 samples which following normal distribution with mean 25. Is this correct?

Comment: The first argument of `rnorm` is the number of data as the sample size,  not the population data. so rnorm(my_trees, mean = 25) will not work.